# Import Excel spreadsheet by column position into MS Access

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

Hi there guys I've got the problem that the file i am importing has no column names and i cannot easily add them on due to other reasons. I do however know which columns i want. So i made a table with the columns position so my vba can loop through and add the respective fields one by one per row. But i seem to get is that the variable isn't being read it thinks that FieldID is a column name. So how do i get vba to understand that is the column i want it to fetch the value from?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rsImport As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFileColumns As DAO.Recordset
Dim CSVCn As Object
Dim rsCSV As Object
Dim strSQL, strName, strName1 As String
Dim rsImporttbl As DAO.Recordset

Set rsImport = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM ImportFiles ORDER BY FileID ASC")
If Not (rsImport.EOF And rsImport.BOF) Then 'This Table how the directory and order in which we want to import the tables.
    rsImport.MoveFirst                      'This helps if there any directory changes or if we need to switch the sequence of import
    Do Until rsImport.EOF = True
        Directory = rsImport!Directory
        FileID = rsImport!FileID
        FileName = rsImport!FileName
        FileType = rsImport!FileType
        DbName = rsImport!DatabaseName

        Set rsFileColumns = db.OpenRecordset("Select FieldName, FieldID From ImportField WHERE FileID =" & FileID & ";") 'This Tells the program which columns we want to import
            If Not (rsFileColumns.EOF And rsFileColumns.BOF) Then 'Also if needed we do have the column numbers stored
                rsFileColumns.MoveFirst
                Do Until rsFileColumns.EOF = True
                    FieldID = rsFileColumns!FieldID
                        Set CSVCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                        Set rsCSV = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

                        strSQL1 = "Provider=" & _
                                  CurrentProject.Connection.Provider & _
                                  ";Data Source=" & Directory & _
                                  ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
                        CSVCn.Open strSQL1 'Tells it where to look for the CSV to import

                        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & FileName & FileType 'Tells what the file is called to import
                        rsCSV.Open strSQL, CSVCn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

                        Set rsImporttbl = db.OpenRecordset(DbName, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError) 'This is the table its appending the data to.

                        Do Until rsCSV.EOF
                            Field1 = rsCSV!FieldID 'Using the column number stored find the value
                            rsImporttbl.AddNew
                                                'please insert it into the same field number into the databases empty verison
                            rsImporttbl.Update
                            rsCSV.MoveNext
                        Loop
                        rsImporttbl.Close
                        rsCSV.Close
                rsFileColumns.MoveNext
                Loop
            Else
                MsgBox "There are no Records in ImportFields for this table: " & FileName
            End If
            rsFileColumns.Close
            Set rsFileColumns = Nothing

    rsImport.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no Records in ImportFiles"
End If
rsImport.Close
Set rsImport = Nothing
db.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use bang notation, and you can use `FieldID` to access a specific field:

`Field1 = rsCSV.Fields(FieldID)` not `rsCSV!FieldID`.

Comment: Thanks worked thank you so much however, it has led to the next problem once its filled out the first Column(the PK) i want to i go back to the top of the list and then start filling out the next column i guess with .AddNew its goes to the last Row and tries to add a new row but that of course conflicts with the PK. Any ideas?

Comment: In this case i want it to fill out 13 columns. {0,1,2,6,10,64,65,66,67,83,86,89,90}

Comment: Eh, just use `.MoveFirst` and `.MoveNext` to move over the recordset again? I'd need a little more context for a more detailed answer, as it's a bit unusual to not just set all fields at once.

Comment: Hopefully this gives more context i have about 10 tables to import i know the order i want them in and i know what column # to import. So i have two tables ImportFiles and import Fields the loop runs through both picking up what files it needs to import and what columns it needs to import so i cant tell it exactly how many fields it needs as that changes from table to table

Comment: which is why i thought maybe if i just do one column at a time it can just move along the columns however, the .AddNew Method creates a new Row which was only required for the first column after that i need to only edit blank rows in the following columns

Comment: Importing one column at a time generally is a bad practice, since you need 13 times as many update operations if you have 13 columns. I'd create an array or collection with all columns you need to update, and iterate over that. I have a function lying around to convert a recordset to a collection, if that helps.

Comment: Yeah i am sure that would a huge help i was thinking it must be something like that I have just never done that so i was a bit lost.

Comment: See [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0bN4UUyH) (not editing it into the answer because it's just loosely related to the question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179175/discussion-between-besarion-and-erik-von-asmuth).

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so I took this further and pretty much i have two tables an ImportFiles table and ImportFields table between these two tables i can direct the program where to go to and what fields to import. This is code.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rsImport As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFileColumns As DAO.Recordset
Dim CSVCn As Object
Dim rsCSV As Object
Dim strSQL, strName, strName1 As String
Dim rsImporttbl As DAO.Recordset
Dim ColumnIDs As New VBA.Collection
Dim ColumnVals As New VBA.Collection

Set rsImport = db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM ImportFiles ORDER BY FileID ASC")
If Not (rsImport.EOF And rsImport.BOF) Then 'This Table how the directory and order in which we want to import the tables.
    rsImport.MoveFirst                      'This helps if there any directory changes or if we need to switch the sequence of import
    Do Until rsImport.EOF = True
        Directory = rsImport!Directory
        FileID = rsImport!FileID
        FileName = rsImport!FileName
        FileType = rsImport!FileType
        DbName = rsImport!DatabaseName

        Set rsFileColumns = db.OpenRecordset("Select FieldID From ImportField WHERE FileID =" & FileID & ";") 'This Tells the program which columns we want to import
        Set ColumnIDs = RSToColl(rsFileColumns, "FieldID")

        Set CSVCn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set rsCSV = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        strSQL1 = "Provider=" & _
                    CurrentProject.Connection.Provider & _
                    ";Data Source=" & Directory & _
                    ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited'"
        CSVCn.Open strSQL1 'Tells it where to look for the CSV to import
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & FileName & FileType 'Tells what the file is called to import
        rsCSV.Open strSQL, CSVCn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

        Set rsImporttbl = db.OpenRecordset(DbName, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError) 'This is the table its appending the data to.
Dim l As Long
Dim value1 As Integer

        Do Until rsCSV.EOF
            For Each Item In ColumnIDs
                Field1 = rsCSV.Fields(Item)
                ColumnVals.Add Field1
            Next
            value1 = 0
            rsImporttbl.AddNew
                For l = 1 To ColumnIDs.Count
                    Value2 = ColumnVals.Item(l)
                    rsImporttbl.Fields(value1) = Value2
                    value1 = value1 + 1
                Next
            rsImporttbl.Update
            value1 = 0
            Set ColumnVals = Nothing
        rsCSV.MoveNext
        Loop
Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no Records in ImportFiles"
End If
rsImport.Close
Set rsImport = Nothing
db.Close
```

Comment: You could eliminate some of the indentation by reversing the first `If`, and then `GoTo` to a finalizer that closes your `RecordSet` and `Database`.